# Variable substitution in commands to be executed by cy.exec() not working

Tags: javascript, cypress

#cat 1.test.ts

`const Name = Cypress.env('file');`
`cy.exec('ls ${fileName}', { failOnNonZeroExit: true });`

I'm writing my tests using Typescript on Cypress. I'm executing a shell command through cy.exec().
While executing `ls ${fileName}`, the `fileName` variable doesn't get substituted with the value from `Name`. Could someone help me with this ?

Comment: Why would you expect it to get substituted? [Template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) use backticks, not quote symbols. Also, please use better formatting for your question. If you have real code (and not an inline "this word is code"), use either code fenced (triple backticks) or block spacing. See [the markdown help article](/markdown) for more details.

Comment: `Name` and `fileName` are two different names, why would that get substituted? Plus as mentioned above, it's a string literal.